# How to check if UICollectionView has a next page which can be displayed?

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uicollectionview

I have `UICollectionView` with `pagingEnabled`. How can I check if collection view has next page which can be displayed if I scroll? I'd like to know about this before any gesture.

Comment: Did you have any ideas? Did you try anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it will be helpful for you.

For Horizontal Scrolling in Collection View

```
int totalPages = floor(self.collectionView.contentSize.width /    
                  self.collectionView.frame.size.width) + 1;
int currentPage = self.collectionView.contentOffset.x / self.collectionView.frame.size.width;
```

If your collection view is going vertically then divide its contentSize's height by its frame's height:

```
int totalPages = floor(self.collectionView.contentSize.height /    
                  self.collectionView.frame.size.height) + 1;
int currentPage = self.collectionView.contentOffset.y / self.collectionView.frame.size.height;
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the `UIScrollViewDelegate`'s 
`-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView` method to understand it. Since `UICollectionView` is built on `UIScrollView` just add this method and it will trigger when user begins dragging when `collectionView` is at the last page:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.x == (scrollView.contentSize.width - scrollView.bounds.size.width)) {
        NSLog(@"this is the end");
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
i assumed the case for horizontal, for vertical:

```
-(void)scrollViewWillBeginDragging:(UIScrollView *)scrollView
{
    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y == (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.bounds.size.height)) {
        NSLog(@"this is the end");
    }
}
```